# KMix and Banshee and other applications

Tags: kubuntu, kde, banshee, volume-control, kmix

Is it possible to control individual applications in KMix (I'm using Kubuntu 12.10) without having to click 'Restore'? I'm hoping for an open-on-right-click temporary window. Also, how do you integrate Banshee into the KMix sound control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**News about KMix – the KDE Multimedia Mixer**

A blog: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/

**Is it possible to control individual applications in KMix**

Yes - with the recent version of the KMix and if the application is supporting the MPRIS2.

**How do you integrate Banshee into the KMix sound control?**
(tested with the Kubuntu 13.04 a1 / KDE 4.10 b2)

Stopping the KMix - adding the backend information to the kmix configuration file - restarting the kmix: http://kmix5.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/winter-of-69-welcome-kmix-v4/ . The developer:" KMix for KDE 4.8" - so it should work with the Kubuntu 12.10.

The Banshee, at here, is in the first KMIx menu and the "Playback streams"

[image]

**KMix main window without restore**
(tested with the Kubuntu 12.10 - KDE 4.9)

The Kmix main window can be launched with the command:

```
qdbus org.kde.kmix /kmix/KMixWindow org.qtproject.Qt.QWidget.show
```

This command can be added to the K-Menu

[image]

so it can be launched with the shortcut key

[image]

or with a quick launcher.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Not exactly what I was looking for, but just as good - or even better. Also, how do I add the backend information to the kmix configuration file? What am I supposed to put in it? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok, never mind. The commands on the site were in such small print I ignored them. Thanks! This is brilliant! I have to apparently wait 8 hours to give you the bounty, so ...

Comment: Just one more question ... when I close the Banshee window, it gets terminated. How do I prevent this? I have MPRIS interface and Sound Menu Integration enabled.

Comment: About the close - Do you want to minimize it to the tray ? A KDE link: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=113&t=102737 Or do you mean something else ?

Comment: That doesn't work very well. It places an icon on the system tray, but removes it when I exit. But the main functionality I'm trying to have is not killing the process when I exit the window.